# Store every request in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm looking to store every request on my store method in laravel. The data comes from checkboxes.

I receive

array(6) {
  ["table2"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["table6"]=>
  string(1) "6"
  ["table8"]=>
  string(1) "8"
  ["table10"]=>
  string(2) "10"
  ["table11"]=>
  string(2) "11"
  ["table14"]=>
  string(2) "14"
}

Is something like this right?

```
public function store( EntryFormRequest $request )
{
 $requetes = $request->except('_token');
 var_dump($requetes);

 foreach ($requetes as $requete) {

     $entry= new Entry;
     $entry->table_id   = $request->input($requete->id);
     $entry->save();

 }
}
```

Note that I got:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'table_id' cannot be null
```

Comment: What is the error there? It looks fine.

Comment: I got column table_id cannot be null

Comment: Hm...based on what you wrote, shouldn't it be `$entry->table_id   = $requete;`?

Comment: Same error if I use this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach ($requetes as $key => $requete) {
 $entry= new Entry;
 $entry->table_id   = $requete->id;
 $entry->save();
}
```

Comment: I found with your answer.
I use $entry->table_id       = $requete;

Comment: `$entry->table_id = $requete;` is literally what I said to do, and you said it didn't work. -__-